# Transactional Integration Testing ASP.Net Core and Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I’m curious if anyone has gone down the road of **transactional integration testing with aspnet and ef core**? I want to be able to perform full integration tests all the way to the db (not using an in-memory db). There are 2 problems:

- Tests can have side effects, but should be run in isolation since side effects could cause other tests to fail. I don’t want the devs to be required to write excessive cleanup code after each test.
- I can teardown and recreate the db every test run but as the test counts start reaching the 100s it becomes unbearably slow to run the tests.

I would like to wrap tests in a transaction (`_dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync()`). The problem is the DbContext I get from:

```
_server = new TestServer(builder);
_services = _server.Host.Services;
_dbContext = (AppDbContext)_services.GetService(typeof(AppDbContext))
```

Will be in a different scope (so a different instance) than the one that gets resolved by the AspNetCore middleware. So, only the test code would be transactional, not any code executed by the `TestServer`. I have considered using some test middleware in a `TestStartup` class that would wrap the API code in a transaction, but the problem there is it will be disposed/rolled back before the test can evaluate it. Consider the following use case:

- send POST to create resource
- assert the dbContext contains the resource

In this case, the test needs access to the *same* dbContext instance used by the test server. 
I tried a few hacky ways of passing the context using `AsyncLocal` which didn’t work so then I just tried using a simple `static` member. <strike>But, that also didn’t work, so it appears there is some AppDomain isolation between the test app and the `TestServer`.</strike>
I’m curious if anyone has gone down this road and if so, what they came up with?

Comment: Why not just use `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory` for testing?

Comment: As stated, I need to go all the way to the db. Our app is using multiple db providers (MS SQL Server and PostgreSQL), we want to also validate migrations which can be provider specific.

Comment: So, you want to alter the database in ways that can make other tests fail and you don't want to write cleanup/revert code?

Comment: Yes. There is the possibility that concurrently running tests could impact each other. Or they may have sideffects that prevent other tests from making the assumption they are running in a clean environment. I want tests to run in a transaction producing no side effects. This is not a new concept and has been in rails for a while (ref transactional fixtures/tests). Tests should not be concerned with whether or not they impact other tests.

Comment: check this out : https://charleskorn.com/2016/03/30/faster-database-testing-with-snapshots/

Comment: did you try to register your dbContext as a Singleton ?

Comment: The singleton solution works! Although it does mean the test fixture and TestServer has to be recreated for every test, but that's much better than dropping and recreating the db every time.

Comment: You can't use singleton if you have concurrently running tests or requests. neither the legacy EF nor EF Core are thread-safe

Comment: ASP.Net Core's DI Singleton is not an implementation of the traditional singleton pattern (i.e. one instance per app domain). Instead it is an instance per `IServiceProvider` instance (in this case, created using a `TestServer`). This works because each test receives a unique `TestServer` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just closing out this issue. The solution was to register the DbContext as a singleton in the test startup class. So, in tests:

```
services.AddDbContext<HostContext>(Configure, ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

But, in the application it would be registered as:

```
services.AddDbContext<HostContext>(Configure, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

UPDATE

A more complete answer has been posted here http://nance.io/leveling-up-your-dotnet-testing-transactional-integration-testing-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: This approach has downside. Imagne that when running application you have navigation property which is null on your entity and when accessing it it throws Null pointer exception. This might not be detected in test because in Singleton DbContext that entity might be rememberd from before and having navigation property set properly. So test might give you wrong picture.